# Insert blank item in j2me form

Tags: java-me, alert, midp, lcdui, gauge

Is there any way to append a blank stringItem in form? I want to show a gauge in a form but it should be center aligned. There is no way to do this I think unless there are a few items before the gauge. So I was thinking to add a few null stringItems but they dont work. This is my code so far.

```
loadingDialog = new javax.microedition.lcdui.Form("Please Wait");
        Gauge gau = new Gauge("\nPlease wait.", false, Gauge.INDEFINITE,
                Gauge.CONTINUOUS_RUNNING);
        gau.setPreferredSize(230,80);
        gau.setLayout(Item.LAYOUT_BOTTOM);
        //Displayable SizeCanvas = new MyCanvas();
        StringItem st = new StringItem(" ", " ");
        loadingDialog.append(st);
        loadingDialog.append(gau);
        parentMidlet.displays.setCurrent(loadingDialog);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special layout directive to center an item, called unsurprisingly, **[LAYOUT_CENTER](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Item.html#LAYOUT_CENTER)**

Using the code snippet you gave, this directive could be set like,

```
gau.setLayout(Item.LAYOUT_BOTTOM | Item.LAYOUT_CENTER);
```

Or, if you want to have it set in a separate statement,

```
gau.setLayout(gau.getLayout() | Item.LAYOUT_CENTER);
```

If your device is MIDP 2.0, this directive is not mandated to follow (although one can expect a device of reasonable quality to support it). In MIDP 2.1 device, it is mandated to be supported by explicit requirement in the specification.

---

By the way, for more advanced purposes of item alignment, there is a dedicated lcdui object called [Spacer](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Spacer.html):

> A blank, non-interactive item that has a settable minimum size. The minimum width is useful for allocating flexible amounts of space between Items within the same row of a Form. The minimum height is useful for enforcing a particular minimum height of a row. The application can set the minimum width or height to any non-negative value. The implementation may enforce implementation-defined maximum values for the minimum width and height...
>
> ...Spacer's primary purpose is to position other item...

Comment: Is it possible to add spacer in first row of form? I am trying to add a spacer then appending gauge. Apparently this does not work.

Comment: is should be definitely possible, MIDP specification allows adding spacer the way you do. _does not work_ may be result of some tricky mis-use of layout / min/preferred size directives. My recollection of working with it was one has to be quite careful to get desired effect

Comment: I found out the problem. The spacer is there but its not being shown. But if I grab the gauge and scroll it down and leave it then it comes to its position i.e after the spacer. The problem is initially the gauge is shown at the top.

Comment: @SoH I see. It's likely a conflict with `LAYOUT_CENTER` directive, which could force Gauge sit at separate "line". As I mentioned with spacers and advanced layout thngs may get tricky quite quickly